# Slider with bullets

Tags: javascript, slider

I have made a slider of three photos. I have two buttons (next and prev), this part works fine. I want to use 3 bullets for selecting the images too, but I am having some problems making the bullet buttons work with the slider. I can't find the way to do this.

Can anyone help me with this code? I'm a real beginner with JavaScript.

Thanks.

```js
/**
 * Navegación por botones
 */
var navegar = function () {
 var elemento = document.getElementById('slider').getElementsByTagName('li');
 var pos = 0;
 for (var i=0; i<elemento.length; i++) {
  if (elemento[i].className == "activa") {
   elemento[i].className = "noactiva";
   pos = i;
  }
 }
 /** Pulsar Anterior **/
 if (this.id == "ant" && pos > 0) {
  elemento[pos-1].className = "activa";
 } else if (this.id == "ant") {
  elemento[elemento.length-1].className = "activa";
 } 
 
 /** Pulsar Siguiente **/
 if (this.id == "seg" && pos < elemento.length-1) {
  elemento[pos+1].className = "activa";  
 } else if (this.id == "seg") {
  elemento[0].className = "activa";
 }
 return false;
};

var desplazar = function () {
 var nav = document.querySelectorAll(".nav");
 for (var i=0; i<nav.length; i++) {
  nav[i].onclick = navegar; 
 }
};

window.onload = function (){
 new desplazar();
};
```

```css
body.slide { background-color:#9c9c9c  }

#slider {display: block; margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;position: relative;width: 50%;min-height: 22.5em; max-height: 22.5em;list-style: none; overflow: hidden;}

#slider li {position: absolute; background: white; float: left; margin: 0 15px 30px; padding: 10px 10px 35px; box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);}

#slider li img { width: 100%;}

#slider .activa { z-index: 1; opacity: 1;}

#slider .noactiva { z-index: 0; opacity: 0;}

.nav { display: inline-block; margin-top: 1.5em; text-decoration: none;}

.botons { text-align: center;}

.button { position: absolute; top: 50%; }

#linknum ul{list-style:none; display:block; text-align:center; }

#linknum ul li{display:inline; margin-right: 3%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PracticaFinal</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slide.js"></script>
  
</head>
 <ul id="navTop">
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="slide.html">Slide</a></li>
      <li><a href="carta.html">Carta</a></li>
 </ul>
<body class="slide">
 <div id="slide">
  <h1>Galeria d'imatges amb Slide</h1>
  <ul id="slider">
   <li class="activa"><img src="images/imatge1.jpg" alt="img1" /></li>
   <li class="noactiva"><img src="images/imatge2.jpg" alt="img2" /></li>
   <li class="noactiva"><img src="images/imatge3.jpg" alt="img3" /></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="botons">
  <button id="ant" class="nav" >Anterior</button>
  <button id="seg" class="nav" >Següent</button>
  
  <input id="button-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="activa" checked="checked">
  <label for="button-1" class="button-label-1"></label>
  <input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="noactiva">
  <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label>
  <input id="button-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="noactiva">
  <label for="button-3" class="button-label-3"></label>


 </div>

 </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find your applications easier to think about if you separate the application *state* from the *representation*. By "application state", we mean the data in the application that changes over time. In this example, the application state has a single property: the currently active slide index.

In order for our code to know the current application state, it must use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) to figure out the index of the slide that is currently active. We can move the state to our code-level by creating a global variable to hold the active slide index:

```
var activeIndex = 0;
```

And while we are creating global variables, let's cache some references to the DOM elements we will be continually using so that we do not have to keep fetching and re-fetching them:

```
var $bullets = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio-set"]');
var $slides = document.getElementById('slider').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Next, let's update our `navegar` function to use our `activeIndex` variable:

```
var navegar = function () {  
    activeIndex += this.id === 'seg' ? 1 : -1;

    if (activeIndex >= $slides.length) {
        activeIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (activeIndex < 0) {
        activeIndex = $slides.length - 1;
    }

    render(); // TODO: We will define this later.
}
```

We will now define our `render` function whose job it will to update the page with the current application state:

```
var render = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++) {
        $bullets[i].className = i === activeIndex ? 'activa' : 'noactiva';
        $slides[i].className = i === activeIndex ? 'activa' : 'noactiva';
    }
};
```

We are now ready to address your original question and to bind the radio buttons to our slider navigation. All we need do is attach an `onchange` handler to each bullet that will update the `ativeIndex` and then call `render`. We can do this by adding something like the following to the `desplazar` function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $bullets.length; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        $bullets[index].onchange = function () {
            activeIndex = index;
            render();
        };
    })(i);
}
```

The `(function (index) { /*...*/ })(i);` bit might look a little odd. If you are curious about it, a discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/3397771).

Additionally, I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/wzj53bs8/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for your help. Is very helpful for me. It's possible make the code without jQuery?

Comment: @daniani: jQuery is _not_ used in my example. I chose to prefix my variables that reference DOM elements with a dollar sign, "$", for convenience; but they could be given any valid identifier name.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sorry, i didn't understand the $ symbol before. I have some problem with the code, when copying it to my program (Sublime Text) the code does not work. Buttons and bullets doesn't make nothing. Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the code in a jQuery ready handler: `$(function () { /** code goes here */ });`. See: https://api.jquery.com/ready/